# Paypal error on Prestashop, shows raw code

Tags: php, paypal, prestashop

we've recently have had problems with payments using paypal in a prestashop. When a customer tries to pay with paypal, it displays the raw code in this file:
/modules/paypal/express_checkout/payment.php

Has anyone else had this problem?

Thank you

Edit: 
PS version: 1.4.0.17
Paypal: 3.8.1

Comment: Recently PayPal has upgraded the security connection, have you (safely) upgraded the module?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't been involved in this website, so I don't know anything about it. It's the latest version, so yes, it should be upgraded. How can I check it?

Comment: Latest PS is PrestaShop v1.6.1.7. You should upgrade as it will include Paypal module too.

Comment: @CaptainSpock The upgrade of PS version from 1.4 to 1.6 it's not so easy. The latest version of PayPal module is 3.10.10, make a backup of all, and upgrade the module.